# Is the Spring Data Jpa isolation level not working?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions, isolation-level

Env

- spring boot 3.1.5
- mysql 8.031

My thoughts were as follows

1. a transaction with isolation level set to SERIALZABLE is started.
2. if the above SERIALZABLE transaction is not finished, but another transaction starts, it will run after the SERIALZABLE transaction finishes.

#### Isolation Code

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository; // JpaRepository
    private Long wait = 5000L;

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public List<Person> findAllSERIALIZABLE() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("SERIALIZABLE ALL start");
        List<Person> all = personRepository.findAll();
        Person person = all.get(0);
        person.setName(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Person person1 = all.get(1);
        person1.setName(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(wait);
        log.info("SERIALIZABLE ALL end");
        return personRepository.saveAllAndFlush(all);
    }

    public List<Person> find1And2() {
        log.info("1,2 find start");
        List<Person> allById = personRepository.findAllById(List.of(1L,2L));
        log.info("1,2 find end");
        return allById;
    }
}
```

#### Test Code

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("SERIALIZABLE find test")
    public void serializableFindTest() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        CompletableFuture<List<Person>> serializableAll = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return personService.findAllSERIALIZABLE();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        CompletableFuture<List<Person>> find1And2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> personService.find1And2());

        List<Person> people = serializableAll.get();
        List<Person> people1 = find1And2.get();

        // then
        Assertions.assertEquals(people1.get(0).getName(),people.get(0).getName());
    }
```

I thought the order would be

1. serializableAll start, end

2. find1And2 start, end

But the result was different.

```java
2023-11-11T14:23:04.585+09:00  INFO 18864 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.tx.test.service.PersonService        : SERIALIZABLE ALL start
2023-11-11T14:23:04.702+09:00 DEBUG 18864 --- [onPool-worker-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name 
    from
        person p1_0
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name 
    from
        person p1_0
2023-11-11T14:23:05.581+09:00  INFO 18864 --- [onPool-worker-2] com.tx.test.service.PersonService        : 1,2 find start
2023-11-11T14:23:05.605+09:00 DEBUG 18864 --- [onPool-worker-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name 
    from
        person p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.id in (?,?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name 
    from
        person p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.id in (?,?)
2023-11-11T14:23:05.610+09:00  INFO 18864 --- [onPool-worker-2] com.tx.test.service.PersonService        : 1,2 find end
2023-11-11T14:23:09.822+09:00  INFO 18864 --- [onPool-worker-1] com.tx.test.service.PersonService        : SERIALIZABLE ALL end
2023-11-11T14:23:09.887+09:00 DEBUG 18864 --- [onPool-worker-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    update
        person 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        person 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
2023-11-11T14:23:09.891+09:00 DEBUG 18864 --- [onPool-worker-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    update
        person 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        person 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
```

I'm not sure if I don't know enough about isolation levels or if I'm setting them up incorrectly.